# How do I use an absolute URL to set as breadcrumb link?

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs

I would like to use absolute URL instead of relative URL as the breadcrumb link on my website. Right now, I am using Drupal 7 and Path Breadcrumb 7.x-3.0 Module. All my breadcrumbs are set by Module.

This is a sample of my breadcrumb right now.

```
<div id="breadcrumbs">
      <h2 class="element-invisible">You are here</h2>
      <div class="breadcrumb">
                <a href="/">Home</a> » 
                <a href="/category.html">Category</a>
      </div>
      <span class="delimiter"> &gt; </span>
      <strong>Dimmer</strong>                            
</div>
```

How can I make the breadcrumbs like these?

```
<div id="breadcrumbs">
      <h2 class="element-invisible">You are here</h2>
      <div class="breadcrumb">
                <a href="http://mywebsite.com">Home</a> » 
                <a href="http://mywebsite.com/category.html">Category</a>
      </div>
      <span class="delimiter"> &gt; </span>
      <strong>Dimmer</strong>                            
</div>
```

**EDIT**

My breadcrumb code is generated by `print $breadcrumb;` in the page.tpl.php file. How can I convert the breadcrumb link from Relative to Absolute in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP code you can build absolute urls with the [url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7.x) function.

Example:

```
$url = url('/category.html', ['absolute' => TRUE]);
```

Comment: I am sorry that my previous question is not clear. I just edited my question. I cannot use URL function since my breadcrumb is generated by `print $breadcrumb;`

Answer (score 0):

You shall put your html in a template and create a preprocess function where you create a variable like this:

```
$vars['url'] = url('/category.html', ['absolute' => TRUE]);
```

Then you have a variable called `$url` that you can use in your tamplate.

Hope it works

Comment: I am sorry that my question is not very clear. In fact, that piece of code in my question is generated by `print $breadcrumb;` in the page.tpl.php file. I couldn't use URL function in this situation I think.